# Hibernate inserting into join table

Tags: hibernate, collections, insert

I got several entities. Two of them got a many-to-many relation. When I do a bigger operation on these entities it fails with this exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert collection rows:
```

I execute the operation i a @Transactional context. I don't do any explicit flushing i my daos. The flush is triggered by a query. In the queue are 15 elements (all of the same structure). one of them always fails (but it's always a different one (I checked) and always at a different position).

Does anybody have a hint for me for what I might do wrong?

My Mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = CategoryImpl.class)
protected Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say with the current level of detail. Is the association bidirectional? Do you have one owning side (with a `mappedBy` on the other side) defined? Can you enable logging to see the executed queries and identify the one which is causing the problem.

Comment: The association is unidirectional. The problem occures on inserting into the join table.

Comment: @Karl Ok. Did you succeed at identifying the SQL statement that is failing?

Comment: The query is this:
Hibernate: insert into PictureImpl_CategoryImpl (PictureImpl_id, categories_id) values (?, ?)
the exception the following:
WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Duplicate entry '2-18' for key 'PRIMARY'
I'm using mysql (5.1.46) innodb with mysql5innodbdialect

Comment: I found a fix. I set flushmode to manual before the beginning of my operation and set it back to auto after finishing... the session was automatically flushed when i queried for something in between. this caused, but the "duplicated entry" is still weired.